# Python: Use Multiple Colors at once in turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, colors

Has anyone ever done this? Using multiple colors at the save time.

I have a list of colors:

```
colors = ["#880000",\
                "#884400",\
                "#888800",\
                "#008800",\
                "#008888",\
                "#000088",\
                "#440088",\
                "#880088"]
```

My aim is to take that list of colors and pass it to turtle so it can draw a colorful circle in one line of turn.

my functions is as follows:

```
def drawImage(colorList, radius):
    for color in colorList:
        turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(0, -radius)
    xpos=turtle.xcor()
    ypos=turtle.ycor()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.setpos(xpos,ypos)
    turtle.circle(radius)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.color('black')
    turtle.width(2)
    turtle.circle(radius)    
    return
```

The problem with the above function is that it draws using only one color instead of little arcs of different colors from the list. can anyone help me solve this or point to what I'm doing wrong?

the function is called like `drawImage(colors,200)` this will draw a colorful circle with a radius of 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this circle ?

[image]

```
import turtle

colors = [
    "#880000",
    "#884400",
    "#888800",
    "#008800",
    "#008888",
    "#000088",
    "#440088",
    "#880088"
]

#--------------------

#turtle.reset()
angle = 360/len(colors)
turtle.width(10)

for color in colors:
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.circle(100, angle)
```

---

There will be more work with filled circle because you have to draw filled "triangle" (arc) one by one.

---

EDIT:

[image]

```
import turtle

colors = [
    "#880000",
    "#884400",
    "#888800",
    "#008800",
    "#008888",
    "#000088",
    "#440088",
    "#880088"
]

#--------------------

def filled_arc(radius, angle, color):

    turtle.color(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(radius)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.circle(radius, angle)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(radius)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.left(180-angle)

#--------------------

angle = 360/len(colors)

for color in colors:
    filled_arc(100, angle, color)
    turtle.left(angle)
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you but you deserve a big thank you, You really saved me a lot of headache. I have been trying everything and none seemed to work till you came to the rescue. Thank so much